# Microsoft Excel 2013 Column value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to have my column in excel have a specific value. For example in column B if I type a 2 in row 2 and a 3 in row 3, I instead of the auto sum giving me 5 I want it to give me 50 is there a way to give the column a value like that ?

Answer (score 2):

This is incredibly simple mathematics. You can do the following formula:

```
=(B2+B3)*10
```

This will multiply the sum of `B2` and `B3` by 10.